# Passport-imap callback?

Tags: passport.js

I'm new to node.js, and am trying to implement imap authentication for a simple test app using passport-imap.

I configured my ImapStrategy and login functions as stated in https://github.com/nettantra/passport-imap, but when I login to my app I get the message "Success fallback is required to generate the user!". Here's my code:

```
passport.use(new ImapStrategy({host: 'my-imap-server', port : 993, tls : true},     function(req,res){
    console.log('AUTH HERE ' ); 
    return done(null, user);
}));

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('imap', {
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}),function(req, res) {
    console.log('OK AUTHENTICATED');
    res.redirect('/app');
  });
```

Adding a "successRedirect" param did not help... can anybody point me to the right direction?

I added a verification callback, but cannot understand what params does it need.
I tried doing something similar to localstrategy, but my "username" param is not what I expected (the user login), it's some other object. Also, I'm not sure this is the way to go: I actually don't want to keep a local userlist, I just want to accept any user that can authenticate to my imap server.

Also I don't understand whether I should use "nextTick" like localstrategy does: if I do it appears my verification is bypassed, and I'm always returned to the login page.

```
passport.use(new ImapStrategy({host: 'my-imap-server', port : 993, tls : true, 
        success_callback: function(username, password, done){
      //      process.nextTick(function () {

      // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
      // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
      // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
      // authenticated `user`.
      findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    //});
        } }
));
```

Comment: Have you defined `findByUsername` function yourself; does it work? How are you actually getting the `user`? You could also just call `done(true, {})` with an empty object as the user.

Comment: @laggingreflex thank you: I have that function defined and working, tested with local-strategy, but my problem is I cannot get data in my callback.
I now have:

passport.use(new ImapStrategy({host: 'imapserver', port : 993, tls : true, 
        success_callback: function(username, imapdata){

Here I cannot get the logged-in username nor data, see also https://github.com/nettantra/passport-imap/issues/2 if you want